# What is the Time Complexity Of the following code ? I am Confused

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

```
array = [1,2,4,5]
sum = 3
def arrfilter2(arr):
    for i in arr:
        if ((sum-i) in arr):
            return True
    return False
print(arrfilter2(array))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jObD.png)

Comment: the time complexity is O(n)

Comment: if ((sum-i) in arr):
            return True
do it take  o (1) ?  not O(n) ?

Comment: A description of a function in terms of big O notation usually only provides an upper bound on the growth rate of the function.

Comment: @bakaDev membership checks for lists are `O(n)` as well, so the worst case is `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the array is not sorted, [`(sum - i) in arr` takes `O(n)`](http://www.cdotson.com/2015/07/python-in-operator-theoretical-vs-actual-time-complexity/) (`n` is the length of the array). In the worst case, the loop scans all of the array. Therefore, **the time complexity is `O(n^2)`.**

By the way, in the best case, it can be resolved in `O(1)`.

If the array is sorted, you can do it better by the binary search technique instead of "in" operator. In that case, the worst case will be `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 0):

**The time complexity is O(n^2)** in the worst case.
In Python, if you search an element using `in` then it scans through the array linearly to find the element.
To compute the Complexity of an algo, in a naive sense, it is **O(n^< no of nested loops>)**. Here you have two nested so it is O(n^2).

you can make it efficient by sorting it first and then using binary search instead of searching linearly using `in`